# the diffrence between "parse" and "expression"

Tags: r

I find there´s a difference between parsing a expression with "parse" function and define the expression using class"expression", here is the code and results.

```
     > a=parse(text="ar1 = 0")
     > b=expression(ar1=0)
     > a
     expression(ar1 = 0)
     > b
     expression(ar1 = 0)
     > a$ar1
     NULL
     > b$ar1
     [1] 0
```

as shown by code,although the both ***a*** and ***b*** are "expression(ar1 = 0)", but there´s no way to consult the element ***ar1*** of ***a***, I want to transform ***a*** to format ***b***, anyone can help me , i ll apreciate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although `parse` returns an `expression`, the structure is not the same as if it was created by `expression()`,

Take a look at `str` :

```
> str(a)
length 1 expression(ar1 = 0)
 - attr(*, "srcref")=List of 1
  ..$ :Class 'srcref'  atomic [1:8] 1 1 1 7 1 7 1 1
  .. .. ..- attr(*, "srcfile")=Classes 'srcfilecopy', 'srcfile' <environment: 0x000000000e0aaa00> 
 - attr(*, "srcfile")=Classes 'srcfilecopy', 'srcfile' <environment: 0x000000000e0aaa00> 
 - attr(*, "wholeSrcref")=Class 'srcref'  atomic [1:8] 1 0 2 0 0 0 1 2
  .. ..- attr(*, "srcfile")=Classes 'srcfilecopy', 'srcfile' <environment: 0x000000000e0aaa00> 
> str(b)
  structure(expression(ar1 = 0), .Names = "ar1")
```

We note that `str(b)` has a name attribute. We could try to give `a` one as well:

```
> a <- structure(parse(text="0"), .Names = "ar1")
> a$ar1
[1] 0
```

Comment: Thank you very much, J.R,  you have solved me a  problem that puzzled me a few days

Comment: or getting the data from `a` we could write: `setNames(as.expression(a[[1]][[3]]), as.character(a[[1]][[2]]))`

Comment: Definitely, thanks for adding. The point is ofc. that the name attribute is missing for `a`